# Why is there no electron swapping after excitation?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons, atoms, orbitals

If we have 2 electrons in the 1st energy level named X & Y, and one electron in the 2nd energy level named Z.

- If the electron X was excited and transferred to the higher energy level, why didn't Z replace it in the 1st energy level?
- Why don't we say that there is a type of nuclear gravity, and it increases when the atom becomes unstable and that gravitates Z electron towards the nucleus instead of the excited one?

Comment: Z might well replace it. But, you put energy in to the system to get X in to another level, so the system will have to release energy to drop Z. I wouldn't quite call this an Auger process, but...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the first part: it will, or won't, in a subsequent, separate process.

If you excite the system and promote an electron from the lowest orbital to the next orbital, the immediate result is that you have a lowest orbital populated by one electron and a higher orbital populated by two electrons. It *is* an excited state, and *will* tend to relax back to the fundamental state if there is an available mechanism to do so - but that will be a second distinct event after the excitation. In fact, the excited state can, depending on the circumstances, last long.

The second part makes no sense. The nature of the interaction between nucleus and electron is not gravitational (it's electromagnetic), and the lowest energy level isn't "below" in any spatial sense. The gravitational analogy is misleading.

Comment: Regarding the gravity part, the electron doesn't fall into the nucleus because of its [kinetic energy](http://www.chem1.com/acad/webtut/atomic/WhyTheElectron.html).

Comment: If we look at this figure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#/media/File:HAtomOrbitals.png we can see that with same probability the electron in 1S orbital occupies smaller volume than the electron in 2S orbital. We can can say that 2S is above 1S. And electrostatic and gravitational forces shares the very same Faraday's and Newton's equation with appropriate constants and measures. The gravitational analogy is quite good in educational terms.

Comment: its most probably a typo but the upper orbital will have one electron not two as you write in line 3.

Comment: @porphyrin If I'm not mistaken, OP asks about a system where the second orbital is already half-occupied (he calls that electron Z).

Comment: @Crowley All hydrogen-like orbitals occupy exactly the same volume: infinity. That's the danger in oversimplifying analogies, we can end up forgetting about the actual properties of the complex system because the simpler image is easier to think about.

Yes, the density of an electron occupying a 1s orbital is, on average, closer to the nucleus than that of an electron occupying a 2s orbital. To say that 2s is "above" 1s opens a can of worms of misconceptions.

Comment: @VicLineal If you look for probability that the electron is in given volume equal to one you are correct. If we look for 0.90 probability or 0.60 probability, the volumes will change. I think the key point here is that 2s orbital has higher energy than 1s orbital. The analogy is perfect when used during introducing a newbie to quantum mechanics but dangerous oversimplifying when used at conference on quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Crowley And expected distance to the nucleus vives you a different ordering. And most likely distance to the nucleus gives you a different ordering. And orbital penetration, which is the most chemically relevant measure, gives you yet another ordering - actually the one we learn by heart as newbies to quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Vic Lineal , yes you are correct, I misread .  And as you state the excited state will last for some time until the energy is released and the ground state is recovered. As electrons are indistinguishable we cannot know which one returns.